# How to use Phaser to make a full-screen version on mobile

Tags: phaser-framework

I saw a lot of api and try a lot of way to make my phaser can using full screen by tap some imgae.

My phaser version is v3.24.1.

I can using

`this.scale.startFullscreen(); // Phaser.Scale.ScaleManager`

It will success for chrome/safari desktop version but not using by phone.

I try a lot of way to make my phaser game can have a fullscreen function.

This my setting:

```
const config: GameConfig = {

    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    parent: 'game',
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH
    },
    scene: [],
    plugins: {
        scene: [
            { key: 'SpinePlugin', plugin: window.SpinePlugin, mapping: 'spine' }
        ]
    }
};
```

I don't want change my screen ratio,just want the screen full on the mobile.

How can I do. please help me.

Comment: the fullscreen api is a web api, and it looks like as far as ios 12 its been unsupported. For what device you’re testing, what might `var supported = Phaser.Device.Fullscreen.available;` be returning?

Comment: Not running. Not just confused.

Comment: ah, actually its  `const available = this.scale.fullscreen.available;`. just opened a project on my iPhone and it was giving false. It's probably still only an experimental feature there. Maybe you could find a solution if this is a pwa or webview app, but in the plain browser you're probably just out of luck

Comment: When I using android it success. Where can I find the rule of the api for iOS. I using caniuse dose not fund the chrome for iOS .

Comment: Tired for that. I using cocos2d maybe finish that problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome on can I use is not the support for the Chrome browser on iOS, they are not the same thing. If you look at Safari for iOS on can I use, it will say Safari & Chrome on iOS. It explicitly says partial support refers to ipad ONLY. Fullscreen Web API is not available on iPhone iOS, regardless of browser.

Your only solutions for fullscreen would be to embed the game in a WebView and install as an app, install the app as a PWA, or enable experimental features for fullscreen if for personal use.

Switching game engine is not going to change whether or not a web api is available for iOS.